# AngularJS get external template and $compile

Tags: angularjs

I have an external template called _include.tmpl.html it's contents are:

```
<script id="sBlock1" type="text/ng-template">
<li ng-repeat="user in users" data-customer-id="{{user.CustomerID}}" ng-class-odd="'alternate'" ng-click="GetOrdersForUser($event)">
    <span class="name">{{user.ContactName}}</span><br>
    <span class="title">{{user.ContactTitle}}</span><br>
    <span class="phone">{{user.Phone}}</span><br>
    <span class="country">{{user.Country}}</span>
</li>
</script>
```

I would like to load the external template, feed it my array of users and get the compiled result? I was trying the below with no luck?

```
 $http.get('_include.tmpl.html', { cache: $templateCache })
        .then(function (response) {

            var test = $compile(response.data)($scope.users);
            console.log(test);
        });
```

The use case is - for infinite scroll. You scroll down, I fetch results from a db feed the results to the template, get the compiled html and append that to the DOM. Each time you scroll down you get more results and the results keep getting appended to the DOM element.

Comment: A template in a template in a template ... What is the desired result? Take into account that compilation alone doesn't necessarily fill a template with all data.

Comment: I want to fill the template with data and get the compiled html... I'm trying to have multiple script blocks in a single html file... have done this with other librarys, just trying to learn the angularjs way

Comment: Compilation and linkage simply don't do what you want. You would need at least one digest cycle. It would be more useful to describe your use case (not just _"get the compiled html"_).

Comment: infinite scroll would be the task of a directive.

Comment: I have edited my post and added a use case.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$compile(response.data)($scope);`.

And considering `_include.tmpl.html` template has been loaded, and `sBlock1` is in template cache, it has to be

```
$http.get('sBlock1', { cache: $templateCache })
        .then(function (response) {

            var test = $compile(response.data)($scope);
            console.log(test);
        });
```

Comment: @charlietfl No, template `script` doesn't need any extra work to be parsed in templates, it is handled by `script` directive. But yes, there is a problem with template, it should be 'sBlock1', not '_include.tmpl.html' to be workable.

Comment: I tried this:       $templateCache.get('templates/_include.tmpl.html');

        $http.get('sBlock1', { cache: $templateCache })
            .then(function (response) {

                var test = $compile(response.data)($scope);

                console.log(test);

            }); but get Error: Access to restricted URI denied

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to mimic what a custom directive can already do for you

HTML

```
<users></users>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('users', function(){
   return {
       templateUrl:'_include.tmpl.html' 
   };    
});
```

This will make the server side ajax call for you and populate the data. It will also store the template in `$templateCache` so another call to server isn't needed

However you would need to remove the wrapping script tag which is part of what is currently causing you problems